# Are Flow Based Generative Models Referring to the Invertible Transformations?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, generative-models

So I have been studying generative models for a while now. I know how GANs and VAEs work quite well, but I am quite confused by how Flow Based Generative Models work.

To my understanding, flow based generative models work by applying invertible transformations to the data. These invertible transformations calculate the log determinant and the latent variable, and when reversed, the transformations calculate the probability of the input data and the inverse log determinant given the latent variable. If that is the case, then the transformation itself (invertible 1x1 convolution, affine coupling etc.) are the generative models themselves. Am I right?

Comment: the invertible transformation together with a standard normal prior on the latent space makes a generative model, yes.